# Not able to display digital signature related details using PDVisibleSignDesigner using pdfbox v2.0.8

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, pdfbox

I have followed [this link](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java?revision=1817604&view=co) to add external digital signature(visible signature) using pdfbox v2.0.8. I am able to see the signature with image in the document but I am not able to see any additional details with this signature rectangle.

Q1. How can we display additional details(like signed by name, reason, signed date or any custom text etc.) as part of digital signature rectangle.

Q2. Is it possible to use `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visiblePDVisibleSignDesigner` and not display any image in digital signature ? I would prefer to display only text information as part of digital signature.

In signed PDF, I can see these details (name, location, reason) are avialable in "Sig" object. Attaching the signed document here.

Some excerpt form Signed document:

```
13 0 obj
<<
/FT /Sig
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Widget
/F 132
/T (Signature1)
/V 16 0 R
/P 4 0 R
/Rect [0.0 753.6 38.4 792.0]
/AP <<
/N 17 0 R
>>
>>
endobj

<<
/Type /Sig
/Filter /Adobe.PPKLite
/SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.detached
/Name (Abhishek)
/Location (Bangalore)
/Reason (Testing Digital Signature)
/M (D:20171213150612+05'30')
/Contents < $(SIGNATURE BYTES) >
/ByteRange [0 2155 21101 12588]                
>>
endobj
```

Comment: This is an open issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3198

Comment: The issue above has been updated with code.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you for the latest example, it works fine.